# Convert date time timestamp in spark dataframe to epocTimestamp

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, apache-spark-sql, java-time, instant

I have parquet file with TimeStamp column in this format `2020-07-07 18:30:14.500000+00:00` written from pandas. When I'm reading the same parquet file in spark, it is being read as `2020-07-08 00:00:14.5`.

I wanted to convert this into epoch timestamp in milliseconds which is this `1594146614500`

I have tried using java datetime format

```
val dtformat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
dtformat.parse(r2.getAs[Long]("date_time").toString).getTime
```

It;s converting but wrong value(1594146614005) instead of 1594146614500.

To make it correct I have to add `dtformat.parse(r2.getAs[Long]("date_time").toString+"00").getTime` .
Is there anyother cleaner approch than this ?

Any function available in spark to read it as milliseconds ?

**update 1:**

After using the below answer:

df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp($"date_time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX")).withColumn("epoch", ($"timestamp".cast("decimal(20, 10)") * 1000).cast("bigint")).show()

```
+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|expected_time|       original_time|          timestamp|        epoch|
+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|1597763904500|2020-08-18 20:48:...|2020-08-18 20:48:24|1597763904000|
|1597763905000| 2020-08-18 20:48:25|2020-08-18 20:48:25|1597763905000|
|1597763905500|2020-08-18 20:48:...|2020-08-18 20:48:25|1597763905000|
```

drawback is suppose if data is at 500ms granularity, then each timestamp has two same epoc timestamp which is not expected.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also there is no way that `SimpleDateFormat` can parse `2020-07-08 00:00:14.5`. It supports only milliseconds, exactly three decimals on the seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you switch from the outdated error-prone date/time API from the `java.util` and the corresonding formatting API (`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`) to the [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and the corresponding formatting API ([`java.time.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html)). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-07-07 18:30:14.500000+00:00",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ"));
        System.out.println(odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1594146614500
```

Answer (score 1):

With the spark dataframe functions,

```
df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp($"time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX"))
  .withColumn("epoch", ($"timestamp".cast("decimal(20, 10)") * 1000).cast("bigint"))
  .show(false)

+--------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|time                            |timestamp            |epoch        |
+--------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|2020-07-07 18:30:14.500000+00:00|2020-07-07 18:30:14.5|1594146614500|
+--------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

this is also possible way to do that.

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus there is drawback in using this, if data is at suppose 500ms granularity then each time stamp has two same values as i updated in the question.

Comment: I dont understand. Your original time is not seen correctly and even the format looks differ.